# How to check if input array has a number, add 1 to it's corresponding index location in output array?

Tags: c, arrays, list, indexing, position

For a class we are required to write a small piece of code that checks an input array for a number, if the number is there it adds +1 to the index location of the output array. Example:

**Input:**

```
1
1
3
2
```

**Output**

```
0 2 1 1
```

In this scenario, there is 2 number 1's, so it's +2 at index location 1 of the output. I'm just not even sure how to go about this? This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void create_hist(double input[], int num_vals, int output[]) {
    memset(output, 0, sizeof(int) * 28);
    for(int i = 0; i < num_vals; i++){
        //HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK//
        }
    }
}

void call_function( const char * label, double x[], int count ) {
    int hist[28 + 1];
    create_hist( x, count, hist );
    printf( "%s\n", label );
    printf( "\tInput data:\n" );

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        printf( "\t%d\t%f\n", i, x[i] );
    }

    printf( "\tHistogram:\n" );

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 28; i++ ) {
        printf( "\t%d\t%d\n", i, hist[i] );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void ) {
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    double x1[] = { 0 };
    call_function( "Count == 0", x1, 0 );

    double x2[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    call_function( "Three equal values", x2, 3 );

    double x3[28 + 1];
    for ( int i = 0; i <= 28; i++ ) {
        x3[i] = i;
    }
    call_function( "One value in each bucket", x3, 28 + 1 );

    double x4[28 * 2 + 1];
    for ( int i = 0; i <= 28 * 2; i++ ) {
        x4[i] = (28+1) * ( double ) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
    call_function( "Random values", x4, 28 * 2 + 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does the first element of your sample output have a `0`? I would expect it to have a `1` like the others.

Comment: @chrisaycock That reads like you see a "0" in the provided sample data. I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input[i]` value as index to `output` array. But before to that you need to check whether the `input[i]` less then  `num_vals`, to avoid out of bound access.

```
   void create_hist(double input[], int num_vals, int output[]) 
    { 
       memset(output, 0, sizeof(int) * 28);
       for(int i = 0; i < num_vals; i++)
       { 
         //You can do as below//
         if(input[i] < num_vals)
         output [input[i]]++;
       } 
    }
```

Comment: How about demonstrating some consistent indentation and clean code formatting. You can teach about StackOveflow customs as well as about C.

Answer (score 0):

The statement below used to generate the values to fill the `input` array will generate `double` values.

```
x4[i] = (28+1) * ( double ) rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

And they are stored in an array of `double`s. 
The histogram generated from this will be flat as every value in the array is likely to be unique. The values have to be truncated or rounded off to have a proper histogram.

Also, the answer [given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914934/10190237) will not work because `double` values are being used as array subscripts.

```
if(input[i] < num_vals)
    output [input[i]]++;
```

Compilation will fail because `input[i]` is a `double`.
For the above to work, the values of `input` array have to be cast to `int` after being truncated or rounded off.